# Matlab: Identifying the Last of a specific number in an array

Tags: matlab

I have an array that my code uses to decide when to do certain functions, lets say its:

and i want to identify the last 5, and note its position in the array so that i can calculate how much time is left in the small sim im building.

What is the best way to go about this?

I'm aware i can make a second loop where all but the 5s are filtered out, but i dont know how i can use that to be able to count to the end?

```
a = [ 0 1 5 5 4 4 3 9 6 5 1 0]

for x = 1: legnth(a)
    if a(x) = 5
        b(x) = 5;
    else 
        b(x) = 0;
    end
end

b = [ 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0]
```

Comment: Why not loop backwards and stop when you hit the first 5?

Comment: see, that is a wonderfull idea i wish i had had 2 hours ago!

Comment: Your loop can be replaced with `b = (a==5) * 5`. `a==5` is a logical array that is `true` where the value in `a` is 5. In an arithmetic operation (`*5`), `true` has a value of 1, and `false` a value of 0, so the multiplication will give you a 5 where the value was 5, and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know the position of the last 5 in your array `a`, use the function [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) as follows:

```
index = find(a == 5, 1, 'last');
```

The second argument, `1`, means find one element. The third argument, `'last'` means to find elements starting from the end.

If there's no element in `a` with a value of 5, `index` will be an empty array.